# Flask or one of its derivatives: one route to handle multiple endponts that are defined in a config file?

Tags: routing, python, flask

We are using Flask-3.0.2 under Python 3.11.

We want to write a highly configurable REST service which manages a few dozen endpoints whose characteristics are defined in a config file (either YAML or JSON) which can be altered whenever we want to add, delete, or change the behavior of any endpoints.

Each endpoint would be managed by a python file which is dynamically loaded at the time that the REST request is being handled.

We don't want to write and re-write decorated python routing functions every time we add, change, or delete routes. We want to have only one, single python routing function which reads the config file and then loads and invokes the matching endpoint-specific dynamically loaded function whenever the incoming URL matches an entry in the config file.

For example, suppose the config file looks like this (YAML example):

```
---
actions:
    /server/func0: func0.py
    /server/func1: func1.py
    /xyz/xyzfunc:  xyzfunc.py
    /abc/abcfunc:  abcfunc.py
...
```

In this example, a URL like `http://example.com/server/func0` sent to our REST server would cause the code in `func0.py` to be dynamically loaded and then invoked, a URL like `http://example.com/abc/abcfunc` would cause `abcfunc.py` to be dynamically loaded and then invoked, etc.

Also, each endpoint could take a set of arguments that would also be passed in via the URL for the REST call or via JSON, and these arguments could differ, depending upon which endpoint is being invoked.

I assume that the Flask code for managing this endpoint could look something like this:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def generic_router():
    # Read the YAML file into a dictionary
    # called `application_endpoints`.

    path = flask.request.path
    loadable_func = application_endpoints.get(path, None)
    if not loadable_func:
        # Handle non-managed endpoint and exit.

    # Import and load the file in `loadable_func` and
    # store the result in a variable called `the_package`.

    # Invoke `func` with the arguments that were
    # passed in, assuming that every imported file
    # must implement a function called `run()`

    results = the_package.run(flask.request.args)

    # Then return the results.
```

I'm guessing that something like this would probably work, but I'm wondering if there might be a better way to do this, perhaps using other features of Flask, or maybe even using Flask-RESTful or some other Flask derivative.

We don't want to use anything other than Flask or one of its derivatives.

To be clear, the goal is to have only one single decorated routing function driven by a config file instead of mutiple decorated routing functions, one for each possible endpoint URL.